# Application becomes sluggish after minimizing

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, garbage-collection

We have a fairly large winforms application that contains all the following:

1. Socket Connections
2. Async Calls to get data from web services thru backgroundworkers.
3. Timers and other events.

The application works fine as long as someone is interacting with it. However if it is minimized for 30 odd minutes or more (say lunch break for example) and then restored, it feels very sluggish and slow and never recovers its original responsiveness and needs to be restarted. 
What could be the connection between minimizing a Winform app for a long time and this unusual unresponsiveness? Perhaps a GC issue but can't find anything. Looking for pointers on what/where to look to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a performance profiler when it gets sluggish?  There are some that let you attach to a running process.

Comment: Also, you mention it's sluggish if it's minimized for 30 minutes.  Do you see the same behavior if it's just idle (but not minimized) for the same time?

Comment: Process memory is likely being virtualized. Install more RAM.

Comment: no its not sluggish if its idle. will look into the profiler thing. We do have ANTS and MEMPROFILER. Let me see what I come up with and report. Thanks.

Comment: If you havent reproduced on several machines then do so first, to rule out obvious things like antivirus or backups kicking in.

Answer (score -1):

If this issue easy to reproduce - I suggest you to attach profiler when you will restore your application after 30 minutes and see what is going on. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182384.aspx

Also you can just attach debugger to see what is going on after you restore your app.